# Subir archivos de google drive a un bucket con app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

estoy tratando de subir archivos guardados en mi google drive a un bucket de google cloud store con app script. Alguien sabe como hacerlo con app scritp? O con python? Cualquiera de las dos opciones me sirve

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Que intentaste o investigaste?

Comment: La pregunta fue _qué intentaste o investigaste_. Debes [edit] tu pregunta para mostrar qué has investigado hasta el momento previo de responder a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si, te paso el código de `Python` con el que lo resolví:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os

ruta_credenciales = "C:xxxx"

ruta_local = "C:/xxxx"

nombre_bucket = 'Bucket'

nombre_subdirectorio_gcs = 'Carpeta_dentro_del_bucket'

credentials_dict = {}
with open(ruta_credenciales, 'r') as json_file:
    import json
    credentials_dict = json.load(json_file)

client = storage.Client.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)

for archivo_local in os.listdir(ruta_local):

        ruta_completa_local = os.path.join(ruta_local, archivo_local)


        ruta_completa_gcs = f'{nombre_subdirectorio_gcs}/{archivo_local}'

        try:

            bucket = client.get_bucket(nombre_bucket)
            blob = bucket.blob(ruta_completa_gcs)
            blob.upload_from_filename(ruta_completa_local, content_type='csv')

            print(f'Se cargó {archivo_local} a GCS en {ruta_completa_gcs}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Ocurrió un error al cargar {archivo_local} a GCS: {str(e)}')
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Debes describir cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer], [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.